# How to check which controller data object being executed?

Tags: laravel

I have faced a typical problem. The problem is which controller data object being executed in view page. Here the data object is **$items**. I have looked most of  controller but can not find data object **$items** . Please help me to find it. Thank in advance. The portion of view page :

```
@foreach($items as $item)
 <div class="partner-logo">
   <div class="inner-div red-box">
     <p>
       <img src="{{ ($item->image) ? asset('file/images/' . $item->image) : "" }}" alt="" />
    </p>
    <h3>
      <a 
       href="{{ isset($item->url) ?route('page.content.show', $item->url) : "#" }}"> {{ $item->title }}
     </a>
   </h3>
   </div>
 </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It seems logical that if it is being used in the view, and you'd like to see where it comes from, that we would need to see the code for the controller.

Comment: I have looked up all controller. But could not find.

Comment: Maybe look through your files for instances where this view is returned. From there, you can see what data is being passed to the view. That should narrow it down.

Comment: Maybe do a search of all files in the text editor for $items = or something like that? If you are using sublime, it'd definitely give you instances where it appears and that would narrow down the scape.

Comment: Have you got any view composers?

Comment: I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, controllers usually pass their data to views in this format:

```
return view('nameOfView', [
    'firstParam' => $firstParam, 
    'secondParam' => $secondParam, 
    'etc' => $etc
]);
```

So you can search in your controllers for the view name and then for the parameter name (in this case `$items`). If there are multiple controller functions with the `$items` param and the same view, add a test param to each and see which one your view renders. You can also check in `routes/web.php` for the current URL you are on, and find the correct controller function that way.

Comment: Basicall this view page is in index.blade.php and contains slider.blade.php

Comment: @rashedcs so first search your controllers for `index` as the name of the view and `$items` as a parameter.

Comment: I have searched but could not find. Have any other way?

Comment: @rashedcs Maybe `$items` is being set in one of the nested views. Look to see if a parent of the view you are examining is setting the var and passing it down to its children.

Comment: Sorry bro, I can't find. Have there use  json?

Comment: @rashedcs Hmm, I don't know, sorry man. In my experience, `$items` should be set somewhere. Maybe do a search of all the views at once and all the controllers, and sift through them, or if you can, ask the original writer of the code.

Comment: @rashedcs It's likely that it's either in a parent blade or in the controller, but it could also be set in the routes file. You could do a search through all your source code for `$items` and change them one by one to `$_items` and see if that breaks the page.